# Rails ajax get data from s3 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I have a **form field** as:

```
<%= select_tag "select", options_for_select(@folders),:include_blank => true %>
```

I'm doing a ajax call as (from `new.html.erb`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#select").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          data: {folder: $(this).val()},
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': '<%= form_authenticity_token.to_s %>'
          },
          url: "/get_files"
      });
    });
});
```

the **`get_files`** action:

```
def get_files
    folder=params[:folder]+"/"
    @files= #getting all the files in a folder as array
    respond_to do |format|
       format.js
    end
end
```

In **`get_files.js.erb`**:

```
$("#audio").html("<%=escape_javascript(render(@files)) %>");
```

In **`new.html.erb`**:

```
<div id="audio">
  <%= render @files if @files %>
</div>
```

In **`_files.html.erb`**:

```
<%= f.input :select_audio, collection: @files, as: :select %>
```

But I'm getting:

## > ArgumentError at /get_files

> '"content.docx"' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.

here `content.docx` is the first file of the `@files` array. What is wrong here?
I'm trying to get all the files of a folder from AWS s3. the user selects a folder and then ajax call is made to `get_files` which responds back with the files in a folder which is an array.
Even if I manually set the `@files` instance variable to say `[1,2,3,4]` I get the same error.

If I set `@files="hello"`, it asks for a `hello` partial. why is this not working?

Comment: you should try submitting the whole from as ajax with remote: true option on the form tag.

Comment: I don't want to submit the whole form via ajax.I'm just trying to update the form fields via ajax call to AWS S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all change

```
$("#audio").html("<%=escape_javascript(render(@files)) %>");
```

to

```
$("#audio").html("<%=escape_javascript(render partial: 'files', locals: { files:@files } ) %>");
```

and then in your partial u should write

```
<%= select_tag "select_audio", options_for_select(files) %>
```

for more info on select tag see [select_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag)

Comment: That worked perfectly. thanks. just had to do a small change. `options_from_collection_for_select` to `options_for_select` as files is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like error in:

```
$("#audio").html("<%=escape_javascript(render(@files)) %>");
```

I think it should be :

```
$("#audio").html("<%=escape_javascript(render 'files' ) %>");
```

to actually be able to render _files.html.erb partial

Comment: Thanks that solved the problem. But now I'm getting  `undefined local variable or method `f' in Class...` Why isn't `f` accessible in the partial?

Comment: Yes precisely, since new request doesn't have context of ```f``` which you might have started in your form. You would have to modify _files.html.erb to instead use *input_tag*  rails helper for same..

Comment: can you show me how to do that? I tried: *<%= render partial: 'files', locals: {:f=>f, files: @files} %> But still same result.